# push,pop,peek,traverse the element of stack statically

Tags: c++, c

enter code herein my program after pushing 5 element i want to traverse all these elements but the output is coming only 0023 that is not desirable so i want correct my traverse portion of the code

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<conio.h>
#define CAPACITY 5
int top=-1;
int stack[CAPACITY];
void push(int);
int isFull(void);
int pop(void);
int isEmpty(void);
void peek(void);
void traverse(void);
void main(void)
{        clrscr();
    int ch,item,i;
    while(1)
    {
        printf(" Options which can be perform : \n");
        printf("1. for push \n");
        printf("2. for pop \n");
        printf("3. for peek\n");
        printf("4. for traverse \n");
        printf("5. for exit \n");

        printf("enter choice u want to enter from above operations : ");
        scanf("%d",&ch);

        switch(ch)
        {
            case 1: printf("enter item u want to push : ");
                scanf("%d",&item);
                push(item);
                break;
            case 2: item=pop();
                if(item==0)
                {
                    printf("stack is underflow\n");
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        printf("pushed element : %d \n",&item);
                    }
                    break;
            case 3: peek();
                break;
            case 4: traverse();
                break;
            case 5: exit(0);
            default:
                 printf("invalid choice enter choice again \n");
        }
    }
}

void push(int ele)
{
    if(isFull())
    {
        printf("stack is overflow\n");
    }
    else
    {
        stack[top]=ele;
        top++;
        printf("Pushed element : %d \n",ele);
    }
}

int isFull(void)
{
    if(top==CAPACITY-1)
    {
        return 1;
    }
    else
    {
        return 0;
    }
}

int pop(void)
{
    if(isEmpty())
    {
        return 0;
    }
    else
    {
        return(stack[top--]);
    }
}

int isEmpty(void)
{
    if(top==-1)
    {
        return 1;
    }
    else
    {
        return 0;
    }
}

void peek(void)
{
    if(isEmpty())
    {
    printf("stack is underflow\n");
    }
    else
    {
        printf("peek item : %d \n",&stack[top]);
    }
}

void traverse(void)
{
    if(isEmpty())
    {
        printf("stack is underflow \n");
    }
    else
    {
        int i;
        printf("elements of stack are : \n");
        for(i=0;i<=top-1;i++)
        {
            printf("%d\n",&stack[i]);
        }
    }
}
```

there is no error its only logical error in the program on pushing element in stack ie 1 2 3 4 5 when i want to traverse these item the output should return 1 2 3 4 5 but its returning 0 0 2 3 why its is so and make it correct too

Comment: Sorry, this ain't C++, it's plain C, mind removing the tag?

Comment: Yep. It also shows that you didn't read the descriptions of the tags that you applied. BTW: As a new user, start with the [tour] and read [ask]. That said, if you have problems with code, you must extract and provide a [mcve].

Comment: Your `printf`s are invalid, causing undefined behaviour.

Answer (score -2):

Your code doesn't return from the program , **main** should `return int` to exit the program . Your push operation is wrong you cant push onto **stack array[top]** as `top=-1` which cant be negative . array indexing should starts from `0`.

Modified working code -

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<conio.h>
#define CAPACITY 5
int top=-1;
int stack[CAPACITY];
void push(int);
int isFull(void);
int pop(void);
int isEmpty(void);
void peek(void);
void traverse(void);
int main(void)
{        clrscr();
    int ch,item,i;
    while(1)
    {
        printf(" Options which can be perform : \n");
        printf("1. for push \n");
        printf("2. for pop \n");
        printf("3. for peek\n");
        printf("4. for traverse \n");
        printf("5. for exit \n");

        printf("enter choice u want to enter from above operations : ");
        scanf("%d",&ch);

        switch(ch)
        {
            case 1: printf("enter item u want to push : ");
                scanf("%d",&item);
                push(item);
                break;
            case 2: item=pop();
                if(item==0)
                {
                    printf("stack is underflow\n");
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        printf("pushed element : %d \n",&item);
                    }
                    break;
            case 3: peek();
                break;
            case 4: traverse();
                break;
            case 5: exit(0);
            default:
                 printf("invalid choice enter choice again \n");
        }
    }
}

void push(int ele)
{
    if(isFull())
    {
        printf("stack is overflow\n");
    }
    else
    { top++; // here you should increment first top from -1 to 0 .coz array indexing is from 0
        stack[top]=ele;
        printf("Pushed element : %d \n",ele);
    }
}

int isFull(void)
{
    if(top==CAPACITY-1)
    {
        return 1;
    }
    else
    {
        return 0;
    }
}

int pop(void)
{
    if(isEmpty())
    {
        return 0;
    }
    else
    {
        return(stack[top--]);
    }
}

int isEmpty(void)
{
    if(top==-1)
    {
        return 1;
    }
    else
    {
        return 0;
    }
}

void peek(void)
{
    if(isEmpty())
    {
    printf("stack is underflow\n");
    }
    else
    {
        printf("peek item : %d \n",stack[top]); // you dont print addresses you need to print values stored in stack array
    }
}

void traverse(void)
{
    if(isEmpty())
    {
        printf("stack is underflow \n");
    }
    else
    {
        int i;
        printf("elements of stack are : \n");
        for(i=0;i<=top;i++)
        {
            printf("%d\n",stack[i]);  // you dont print addresses you need to print values stored in stack array
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Also, you seem to print *addresses* of elements of the stack `&stack[i]` in `printf`-s, and not the actual values. I am a bit confused though why you get sane numbers in the output.

Comment: i had debugged the code now . it may contain more bugs but i helped him some .

Comment: Them. I added it as a comment to yours as an addition to what you said.